# Cannot install npm i node-resemble OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, npm, resemblejs

```
tmp-125-48:engineerappcopy User$ npm i node-resemble
npm WARN package.json cloudfmapp@1.0.0 No README data

> canvas@1.6.2 install /Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/node_modules/node-resemble/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

./util/has_lib.sh: line 31: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to './util/has_lib.sh freetype' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/node_modules/node-resemble/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "node-resemble"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.6.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.6.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs canvas
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have Homebrew? If so, try `sudo brew install pkg-config` then rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-resemble-js

Does not require canvas or Cairo